# Considered as a wave, shouldn’t a photon’s energy decrease with distance from its point of emission?

Tags: photons, wave-particle-duality

I'm referring to this https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/543059 question and its most voted answer.

If we view the photon as an electromagnetic wave, the field strength should diminish with distance, as the wave front expands.  How could then a photon coming from a distant star have enough energy to be detected by our electronic equipment (which relies on the Compton effect)?
Also, a spherical wave reaching some body would interact with ALL its electrons, and if the wave front has enough energy it could kick them all out of their orbits, creating a plasma!

Comment: Yes, sure, the double slit experiments. In the question-answer I mention someone thinks (rightly or wrongly, it does not matter at all) that there would be an extremely low probability that a photon would hit an electron, the ‘particles’ being so small. And someone answers and waves away the difficulty by saying that it is a wave front hitting the electron, same as a radio wave hitting my radio antenna without any difficulty. And what I’m asking is: if you accept that ‘solution’ to the question asked in that other post, don’t you have to deal with all the consequences of a photon being a wave?

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing *energy* and *intensity*, which is a measure of flux. An expanding wavefront doesn't lose *energy*, but that energy is now spread out over a greater *area*(because, well, it is expanding). This means that the flux, roughly $E/A$, is decreasing. $E$ cannot decrease ofcourse-energy is conserved.

This flux is what we perceive as intensity. A torch from far away looks dimmer not because the light it let out lost energy before reaching it, but simply because not enough of it is reaching it-it has spread out.

Comment: I have not used the terminology rigorously, hence your answer. Of course I meant the energy carried by the wave at a particular spot, that is: the ability to do some work (the definition of energy) at any spot of the wavefront would be diminished with distance. I know that is not the case, hence my question.

Comment: So even a single photon "spreads out" over time in terms of its energy/area? So at infinite distance from the source of the photon, there'd be (practically) no photon left to observe, right?

Comment: @Dunois not really. The energy of a given photon remains the same, $h\nu$. A beam's energy is determined by not just the frequency of one photon, but also the number of photons. As the wave front spreads, the same number of photons is now spread over a greater area. The number density of photons is is a measure of intensity, and thus the intensity decreases. So, a 'single' photon doesn't spread out, but the beam does, and thus you practically have no photon left in a small enough area-they are distributed over  a large area.

Comment: @GRrocks I believe OP's question was actually about a **single** photon as a wave (and I was following along in that context). You answered in the context of a beam, but I reiterate: what would happen to a single photon? Shouldn't the same thing that happens to a beam also happen to a single photon? I'm looking forward to your inputs!

Comment: @Dunois a single photon's frequency is fixed by the source, and it's speed is constant. If you model it as a plane wave, then nothing happens. The photon moves without the wave spreading. What you probably have in mind is a wave PACKET-which spreads out, as in usual QM, but that's because it's localised, and thus the uncertainty principle(UP) comes into play. A plane wave has a well defined momentum, but no position, and so there is no spreading of the wavefunction via UP. However, in an accelerating universe, the frequency redshifts, and the photon does lose energy. But thats irrelevant here.

Comment: @GRrocks that clears up things a little better for me. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The photon model would merely spread a set number of photons over a larger area (scaling as $r^2$). Therefore what happen is the number of photons per unit area decreases. The photon energy does not change.