# Can photon frequency and photon number be measured simultaneously?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-optics

Can the photon frequency and the photon number be measured simultaneously?

The question arises the in context of the Compton scattering ([see here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/543063/247642) for the original discussion), where one would need to measure *the frequency shift of a single photon*. Although measuring a single photon (or a very low photon number) might be possible using a photon counter, I doubt that it can be done simultaneously with measuring its frequency.

Could you formulate it in basic quantum-mechanical terms, e.g.,  is as non-commutativity of two operators: "frequency operator" and the number of particles?
I would also appreciate a relevant discussion of what is possible experimentally in this respect.

**Remark**
I would like to note that single-mode approach doesn't help. I.e., if we start with a single mode, then the operators of the energy of the field and the number of particles are
$$\hat{H}=\hbar\omega b^\dagger b,\hat{n}=b^\dagger b.$$
However, we cannot measure the frequency by measuring the energy and the particle number and then dividing them one by the other, since *these are given by the same operator*. Thus, in practice measuring energy in such single-mode case means measuring the particle number and multiplying it by the known frequency.

One could approach the problem in this spirit by assuming that we have a field with potentially many modes, and we want to measure how many photons are in each of them:
$$\hat{H}=\sum_\omega\hbar\omega b_\omega^\dagger b_\omega,\hat{n}_\omega=b_\omega^\dagger b_\omega.$$
(We are ultimately interested in the limit of one photon.)

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can, just enter the photons into a prism or a grating (something that redirects light as function of frequency) and put a photodetector in bin. The photodetector will tell you the number of photons, and its position will tell you their frequency.

Comment: So you are saying that photons of different frequencies can be made to have different mode structure. Isn't there still some limitation?

Comment: Not anything theoretical. There are practical issues about resolution of a spectrometer, dealing with how close you can make the lines in a grating, or which material has a really high dispersion relation such that a prism will split different wavelengths efficiently. (But there are a couple of schemes how to get still a higher spectral resolution)