# Atom emits photon when electron changes energy levels -- is this related to moving charge emitting e/m radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons

Not much more than what I asked in the title. I think it is true that a moving charge emits photons also.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544239/how-exactly-does-an-electron-falling-back-to-its-original-state-from-an-excited/544343#544343

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is related. It is basically the same physics as the emission of radio waves from radio aerials. In both cases an oscillating charge emits a photon of a frequency equal to the frequency of oscillation.

In an atom it isn't obvious how there could be an oscillating charge, but there is. Explaining why an oscillating charge exists is a bit involved but if you fancy a challenge there is an excellent description of how this happen in Emilio Pisanty's answer to the question [Is there oscillating charge in a hydrogen atom?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293359/is-there-oscillating-charge-in-a-hydrogen-atom) Roger Barlow has linked the question [How exactly does an electron falling back to its original state from an excited state produce electromagnetic waves?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544239/how-exactly-does-an-electron-falling-back-to-its-original-state-from-an-excited) and his answer is also an excellent desription, though I think Emilio's is easier for the beginner.